# Android NDK. Not a JPEG image: starts with 0x00 0x00

Tags: android, android-ndk, libjpeg

I want to use jpeg images in my Android NDK application. I downloaded libjpeg9 and successfully compiled it as static library. I load an image from apk with libzip and when I begin reading header of the image I get the following error: "Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x00 0x00". The same error is occured when I launch my application in emulator and real device as well. I type in Terminal command to check my file: "file myjpeg.jpg" and get the following message: "myjpeg.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01" so file is valid. Moreover, if I load the same image from file with `jpeg_stdio_src` function in MacOS app I get success. Part of code is responsible for loading jpeg files in Android:

```
zip * apk = zip_open(apk_path.c_str(), 0, NULL);
if (!apk)
    return false;

zip_file * fp = zip_fopen(apk, path.c_str(), 0);
if (!fp)
{
    zip_close(apk);
    return false;
}

JSAMPARRAY buffer;
int stride;

jpeg_error_handler jerr;
jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;

cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr.pub);
jerr.pub.error_exit = jpeg_error_exit;
jerr.pub.output_message = jpeg_error_msg;

unsigned char * imageData = NULL;
if (setjmp(jerr.setjmp_buffer))
{
    jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);
    zip_fclose(fp);
    zip_close(apk);
    if (imageData) free(imageData);
    return false;
}

struct zip_stat st;
zip_stat_init(&st);
zip_stat(apk, path.c_str(), 0, &st);
if (st.size <= 0)
{
    zip_fclose(fp);
    zip_close(apk);
    return false;
}

imageData = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * st.size);
memset(imageData, 0x0, sizeof(unsigned char) * st.size);

jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
jpeg_mem_src(&cinfo, imageData, st.size);

jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);
jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);
stride = cinfo.output_width * cinfo.output_components;
buffer = (*cinfo.mem->alloc_sarray)((j_common_ptr) &cinfo, JPOOL_IMAGE, stride, 1);

jpg->width = cinfo.image_width;
jpg->height = cinfo.image_height;
jpg->colorMode = cinfo.output_components;

log("Loaded: " + path + " width: " + StringUtils::intToStr(jpg->width) + " height: " +
            StringUtils::intToStr(jpg->height) + " color mode: " +
            StringUtils::intToStr(jpg->colorMode));

// read jpeg image...
```

How can I read correct data from the file? I suppose the file isn't loaded into buffer by `jpeg_mem_src` but I don't know about reasons. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you setting imageData to the jpeg data from the apk?

Comment: I think that jpeg_mem_src will initialize imageData. I have read about it here: http://www.christian-etter.de/?tag=jpeg_mem_src. There is description of jpeg_mem_src: "The following function performs initialization of the memory buffer. "

Comment: But you filled `imageData` with 0's - you need to fill it with the jpeg data to be decoded.

Comment: In this case could you tell me how can I read this data and what jpeg_mem_src do?

Comment: `jpeg_mem_src` just tells the library where your "decoded jpeg data" is located. You need to pass in a pointer to this data. You are retrieving it from the APK.

Comment: Thank you very much! You're really help me. I changed memset to zip_fread and image have been loaded successfully.

Comment: Oops - solved in the comments! I'll add this solution as an answer ;) Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you aren't telling the library where the image data is. `imageData` is set to 0's then passed to the library.

`jpeg_mem_src` just tells the library where your "decoded jpeg data" is located. You need to pass in a pointer to this data.

It looks like you are retrieving this from the APK, try passing a pointer to the data into `jpeg_mem_src` instead.